# Is jQuery.extend safe from circular reference?

Tags: javascript, recursion, merge, circular-reference, cloning

Is `jQuery.extend` safe from `circular reference` ?

How can one avoid circular reference in Javascript (while cloning or checking recursively) ? Just checking for the existence of current target in its property list is not sufficient as it may refer to some external object.

One option is to keep another list of all `objects` fetched till now. but would that increase memory consumption and ask to stop the script ?

and I don't want to move the cloning operation in worker thread.

Comment: Depending on the size of the object, what about `JSON.stringiy`ing it and check whether it failed? `JSON.stringify` will fail if the object contains a circular structure, and (at least on Chrome) you can nicely catch this specific case with `try catch`.

Comment: You don't need to check for circular references.  They are handled fine unless you stringify them, in which case they will not include the circular reference(s).

Comment: I want to merge two objects recursively. so there is a chance that it will enter in a loop infinitely if there exist a circular reference. I don't understand significance of `stringify` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I was looking for this today - the answer is: no.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

> On a deep extend, Object and Array are extended, but object wrappers on primitive types
>   such as String, Boolean, and Number are not. **Deep-extending a cyclical data structure
>   will result in an error**.
>
> For needs that fall outside of this behavior, write a custom extend
>   method instead, or use a library like lodash.

The lodash docs are not very clear, but _.cloneDeep supports cloning circular references.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep

You are better off using something clever like lodash as I think it will correctly detect all the objects referenced more than once and create a true clone of the entire object graph with all circular references intact.

However, here is a naive deep clone that simply ignores a circular reference using a simple stack of objects (it's in TypeScript):

```
public static DeepClone(source: any, stack: any[] = null): any
{
    if (!source)
    {
        return source;
    }

    var result;

    result = Array.isArray(source) ? [] : {};

    for (var k in source)
    {
        var v = source[k];
        if (typeof v === "object") 
        {
            stack = stack || [];

            // Just ignore circular references? Or, to be clever, maintain a 
            // dictionary of object references from the original graph linked to
            // the new objects in the cloned graph, to preserve the full graph.
            if (stack.indexOf(source) >= 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            stack.push(source);

            result[k] = this.DeepClone(v, stack);

            stack.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            result[k] = v;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```